# Deduplicate kafka events with kafka streams before reaching consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have application which consuming events from kafka topic and on this topic each one event is duplicated (I cannot change it cause it is an external app behind that).
I would like to provide deduplication there (based on key).
I'm using spring boot and I think that kafka stream could be used there nicely.
I implemented this behaviour but it is wrong cause my consumer still getting the same event twice.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaStreamsConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String applicationId;


    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "deduplication-id");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE_V2);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }


    @Bean
    public KStream<String, String> kStream(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        KStream<String, String> stream = streamsBuilder.stream("inputTopic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeAndGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(30), Duration.ofMillis(3000)))
                .reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue)
                .toStream()
                .map(((stringWindowed, value) -> new KeyValue<>(stringWindowed.key(), value)))
                .to("outputTopic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        return stream;
    }
}
```

My consumer look like that:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = {"output-topic"}, groupId = "spring.kafka.consumer.group-id")
    public void consumeEventRelease(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord)  {
        log.info("Kafka consumer received message {}", consumerRecord.value());
        //some further implementation
    }
```

As you can see I also used 'exactly_once' property.
I'm not sure what am I missing here, I would appreciate some help. Maybe I should use spring-cloud-streams for it?

Answer (score 0):

How can you be sure that each kafka event is duplicated?
If you find out this situation by reading logs(

> log.info("Kafka consumer received message {}", consumerRecord.value())

). Here is a pertential reason for explaining duplicated event.

In my project, I use logback as log framework.
And I defined two logback Appender in the project.

1. One appender logs all level project info.
2. Another Appender simply logs error-level project info.
   In this case, error-level logs will be printted twice.

SO, Maybe you are just reading duplicate logs, not duplicated events in Kafka. If you want to verify, simply compare the timestamps of the two logs. The same timestamps indicate the same log.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't explained it well. There are two instances of microservice  which are doing exactly the same, reading some external messages and send them with helps of Kafka Producer to the same topic (both have the same, unique for them key). And this is a part I can't change, it is just how it works. My part is to receive those events and deduplicate them based on key so at the end I would like to have no events with the same key

Comment: If your upstream team sends two identical messages with different keys, I believe it's a critical bug, and the upstream project should not proceed with the release without enough tests. The best approach for me is to communicate with them to address the issue. If you are unable to connect with them, there is a backup option available. You can save all the messages and compare them before processing. It may not be elegant, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a code example at hand, but I've done what you're trying to do with Flink, which is kind of similar to KafkaStreams.

You'd have to do following:

1. Create a custom `FixedKeyProcessor`/`FixedKeyProcessorSupplier` and introduce a key value state store (with your key type and a boolean "seen").
2. In the `process()` function you check the state store if your key exists - if not you create an entry in the state with your key and `true` and forward the record. If it exists and your boolean is true, you don't forward the record (in that sense swallow it, as it is a duplicate).
3. This processor needs to be included in your topology by appending `.processValues(new MySuperCoolFixedKeyProcessorSupplier())`.

This will effectively be a filter function, which only lets messages through that have not been seen before, the list of seen messages being your state store, which will be constantly growing with every processed key. Of course you need to think about retaining your state in case of errors, which has some complexities in itself.

The boolean variable is actually redundant, but it seems there is no single value store interface - you will never have the situation where you have a key in your state store which has "seen" set to `false`. In case I'm mistaken (as mentioned, I initially performed this with Flink, not KafkaStreams) and there is a fitting StateStore interface, feel free to edit this and correct.